# Getting <empty items> at the beggining and not random numbers result while array push method call

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say that I want to create an Array with random size:

```
const generateNumber = (min, max) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + Math.floor(min);
const array = Array(generateNumber(5, 10));
```

and for even indexes of array put numbers from range <a,b> and for odd index put number from the range <c,d>.

So far I have a code like:

```
const array = Array(generateNumber(5, 10));
for (let [index, val] of array.entries()) {
  if (index % 2 === 0) { // index is even
    array.push(generateNumber(10, 10));
  }
  if (index % 2 === !0) {
    array.push(generateNumber(30, 30))
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

but I am receiving result:

```
[ <5 empty items>, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
```

I am new in JavaScript and I am a little confused about what I am doing wrong. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to solve the problem.

EDIT:
I misunderstood `push()` method assumption. Below code works as expected:

```
for (let [index, val] of arr.entries()) {
  if (index % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log("Index: %O", index)
    arr.splice(index, 1, generateNumber(10, 20));
  } else {
    arr.splice(index, 1, generateNumber(20, 30));
  }

}
console.log("Generated array: %O", arr)

for (let index in arr) {
  if (index % 2 !== 0) {
    arr.splice(parseInt(index), 1, generateNumber(30, 60));
  } else {
    arr.splice(parseInt(index), 1, generateNumber(20, 50));
  }
}
```

Thanks for your commitment.

Comment: `Array(5)` generates an array that has its `length` set to 5 already, and pushing to an array simply adds elements at index {current length + 1}. Assign the elements via index directly.

Comment: And `if (index % 2 === !0)` doesn’t work like that, you negate a comparison by using the negated operator, not be negating one of the values. This would need to be `if (index % 2 !== 0)`, but since there is only _one_ possible alternative to the first `if` here, you should rather make than an `else` branch to begin with.